# How to disable Paging in WebGrid

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, webmatrix, webgrid

I've searched the documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.webgrid.webgrid(v=vs.111).aspx), and found "canPage: false" - which does not work. Saying there is no parameter named 'canPage'.

Other sites have said 'autoSortAndPage: false' works, but it hasn't worked for me.

Code:

```
<div id="grid">
    @grid.Html(canPage: false,
      // the rest of my grid stuff
    );
</div>
```

How can I get rid of this paging?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It's `canPage`, but that's a parameter of the `WebGrid` constructor.

```
@{
    var grid = new WebGrid(canPage: false,
      // ... etc
    );
}

<div id="grid">
    @grid.GetHtml()
</div>
```